# Creating a Mailing Script for Newsletters

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am currently using PHP mailer. I would like to create a mailer script where I can add an arbitrary (anywhere from 10-1000) number of fixed e-mails and type in a message in a textarea and the mailer will mail each person the e-mail individually rather than all at once. I would like to avoid users opening an e-mail that appears to be sent to 1000 other e-mail addresses and make it more personal (i.e. sent from e-mail address x to y, as opposed to, sent from e-mail address x to a,b,c,...) This will simply be an administrative extension for admins to easily mail out newletters to all subscribers.

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to implement this? I would rather stay away from cron jobs, if it is possible to implement this without it.

I appreciate any advice.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's rather a large question this one! Do you understand HTML forms? If so, then the textarea bit shouldn't be a problem. Your script will need to send a separate email to each recipient – you'll probably want to add a delay between each send, depending on your server and mailserver's settings.

Comment: Thank for the reply. Yes, I understand HTML forms, I would know how to e-mail an arbitrary number of emails at once using php mailer, and I would be able to tie the form into an HTML text area, however, implementing the individual sending of the message to each e-mail address, and creating the delay between sending, is where I am having difficulty.

Comment: Ah okay. Well, you'd need to loop through each email address in your database, setting the email's "To" address each time. (Either clear the "To" value, or re-create the PHPmailer object instance each time.) Use PHP's ```sleep``` function to wait between each iteration of the loop.